# How can I revert the efect of padarray, in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

This is waht I do to add the padding, I do some operations, and then I need to take off the added padding.

```
imageP = padarray(image, [pad, pad]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

`[row, col] = size(originalImage) % Matrix dimensions`

`imageP = padarray(originalImage, [pad, pad]); % Add padding`

`originalImage = imageP(pad+1: row-pad, pad+1:col-pad)    % Revert padding`

Answer (score 0):

A previous answer yields an empty array instead of the expected result due to operator precedence in the array indexing on the last line. I suggest the following adjustment:

```
% image and padding for testing
originalImage = magic(4);
pad = 2;

[row, col] = size(originalImage) % Matrix dimensions
imageP = padarray(originalImage, [pad, pad]); % Add padding
revertedImage = imageP(pad+(1:row), pad+(1:col))    % Revert padding
```

Now the indexing arrays have the required sizes `row` and `length`, and the original array is recovered (i.e., `originalImage` == `revertedImage`).